# geolocation not working in mobile browser

Tags: mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

So I mad a map with mapbox with UI and Geolocation, working perfect on PC however...

In a mobile browser the Geolocation function is disabled and the browser isn't asking GPS permission.

Any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: You will want to include details about which browser and operating system.

Comment: Google Chrome Mobile